# Changing the colour of a single data item, in a Google Charts Histogram

Tags: charts, google-visualization, histogram

I'm experimenting with the code found on [Google Chart's website](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/histogram#example), with an additional option of setting the buckets to represent a 10% percentile each:

```
var options = {
  title: 'Lengths of dinosaurs, in meters',
  legend: { position: 'none' },
  histogram: { bucketSize: rawData.length / 10}
};
```

However I cannot find a way, from looking at the documentation, to change the colour of a single data point, so that the graph resembles this:

[image]

Is there a workaround using Javascript and / or the Google Charts exposed methods, in order to achieve this?

Pastebin link to my code (with the change detailed above): https://pastebin.com/NeGnEwKY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there aren't any standard options you can use to change the color of a specific block

but you can change the color manually

the chart will draw the blocks in order of the value (`'Length'`)

first, sort the data by value

```
// sort data by 'Length'
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rawData);
data.sort([{column: 1}]);
```

now the data table will be in the same order as the `<rect>` elements used to draw the chart

we can use `getFilteredRows` to set the row indexes to be highlighted

```
// find data row to highlight
var highlightRows = data.getFilteredRows([{
  column: 0,
  value: 'Ultrasaurus (ultra lizard)'
}]);
```

next, we can use the `colors` option to identify the block elements (`<rect>`)
then change the `'fill'` property

but we have to use a `MutationObserver`, because the chart will revert back to the original color,
anytime there is activity, such as on hover, or select...

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages:['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var rawData = [
    ['Dinosaur', 'Length'],
    ['Acrocanthosaurus (top-spined lizard)', 12.2],
    ['Albertosaurus (Alberta lizard)', 9.1],
    ['Allosaurus (other lizard)', 12.2],
    ['Apatosaurus (deceptive lizard)', 22.9],
    ['Archaeopteryx (ancient wing)', 0.9],
    ['Argentinosaurus (Argentina lizard)', 36.6],
    ['Baryonyx (heavy claws)', 9.1],
    ['Brachiosaurus (arm lizard)', 30.5],
    ['Ceratosaurus (horned lizard)', 6.1],
    ['Coelophysis (hollow form)', 2.7],
    ['Compsognathus (elegant jaw)', 0.9],
    ['Deinonychus (terrible claw)', 2.7],
    ['Diplodocus (double beam)', 27.1],
    ['Dromicelomimus (emu mimic)', 3.4],
    ['Gallimimus (fowl mimic)', 5.5],
    ['Mamenchisaurus (Mamenchi lizard)', 21.0],
    ['Megalosaurus (big lizard)', 7.9],
    ['Microvenator (small hunter)', 1.2],
    ['Ornithomimus (bird mimic)', 4.6],
    ['Oviraptor (egg robber)', 1.5],
    ['Plateosaurus (flat lizard)', 7.9],
    ['Sauronithoides (narrow-clawed lizard)', 2.0],
    ['Seismosaurus (tremor lizard)', 45.7],
    ['Spinosaurus (spiny lizard)', 12.2],
    ['Supersaurus (super lizard)', 30.5],
    ['Tyrannosaurus (tyrant lizard)', 15.2],
    ['Ultrasaurus (ultra lizard)', 30.5],
    ['Velociraptor (swift robber)', 1.8]
  ];

  // sort data by 'Length'
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rawData);
  data.sort([{column: 1}]);

  // find data row to highlight
  var highlightRows = data.getFilteredRows([{
    column: 0,
    value: 'Ultrasaurus (ultra lizard)'
  }]);

  var options = {
    colors: ['#3366cc', '#dc3912'],  // <-- 1st color used to identify, 2nd to highlight
    title: 'Lengths of dinosaurs, in meters',
    legend: { position: 'none' },
    histogram: { bucketSize: rawData.length / 10}
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Histogram(container);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function () {
      var index = 0;
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('rect'), function (rect) {
        if (options.colors.indexOf(rect.getAttribute('fill')) > -1) {
          if (highlightRows.indexOf(index) > -1) {
            rect.setAttribute('fill', options.colors[1]);
          }
          index++;
        }
      });
    });
    observer.observe(container, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    });
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```